# android:how to detect network is connected to internet

Tags: android, networking

I have this code to check for internet connection.

```
NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

             //if network is active and have internet connection 
            if(info != null && info.isConnected()==true){


            //Some code


            }

     //if network is inactive or doesn't  have internet connection 
     else   if(info == null || info.isConnected()==false){

               Context context = getApplicationContext();
               CharSequence text = " Bad internet connection.";
               int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
               toast.show();

             }
```

When I start the program,everything works properly with turn on internet connection,but when I pull out the internet cable from my router and in my app still have turn on wifi the app get true with this (if(info != null && info.isConnected()==true)) and crash.I don't know why this code get true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use this for check condition of network:

if (info!=null && info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
}
```